# How can i appear, in every product category, the price filter from Faceted Search in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop

in Prestashop i tried to appear the price filter for every products categories, so activated it from Faceted Search -> Configure and enabled the price filter slider, but after that, the price appeared in some of the product categories. So my problem is, how can i appear the price filter and on the other categories products?

The Prestashop version is 1.7.5.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: Have you noticed any dependency between categories where filter doesn't appear? Maybe those categories don't have more than one product? Or maybe some other similar traits?

Comment: If I remember correctly, as @AlexanderGrosul said, filter is not displayed if it correspond to every product displayed